# How to convert data to a serialized tf.Example(tensorflow tfrecords) using Golang

Tags: go, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Is there a Golang API to convert data to a serialized tf.Example, also known as tensorflow tfrecords.

I can find a Python api `tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter()` to achieve this.

But examples with golang can not be found.

I want do this coz i use a golang client to call the tensorflow serving and my input feature for nn is a SparseTensor.

Comment: The best I see from the doc is [this](https://godoc.org/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go#Tensor.WriteContentsTo)

Comment: @Adonis thanks for you reply. It seems the `WriteContentsTo` api just writes the serialized contents of tensor to an `io.Writer`, but not in a [tf.train.Example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/core/example/example.proto) format.

Answer (score 2):

`tf.Example` refers to a protocol buffer, while `tfrecords` typically refers to a file format which stores "records" in the form of strings (which is why [`tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter.write()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/python_io/TFRecordWriter#write) takes a string). So the two are separate things, not technically related. Though often one serializes `tf.Example` protocol buffers into a strings, one each per records in a `TFRecordWriter`.

That said, it is common for models to take as input a serialized `tf.Example` protocol buffer as input in the form of a `STRING` tensor. If that is the case, then you'd want to construct the `tf.Example` protocol buffer in Go and then use [`proto.Marshal`](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto#Marshal) to construct the `tf.Tensor` object to feed.

Unfortunately, as of January 2018, you have to generate the Go files for the `tf.Example` protos yourself. That can be done with something like:

```
# Fetch the tools
GOPATH=$(go env GOPATH)
go get github.com/golang/protobuf/proto
go get github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go

# Create a directory to generate the files
mkdir -p /tmp/protos/out
cd /tmp/protos

# Clone the TensorFlow sources to get the source .proto files
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow ./src
PATH=$PATH:${GOPATH}/bin

# Generate Go source files from the .proto files.
# Assuming protoc is installed.
# See https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases
protoc \
  -I ./src \
  --go_out ./out \
  ./src/tensorflow/core/framework/*.proto ./src/tensorflow/core/example/*.proto
rm -rf ./src
```

This will generate a bunch of `.pb.go` files in `/tmp/protos/out` which can be used to build the `tf.Example` protocol buffer structures to marshal.

Hope that gives you enough information to get going.

Comment: hi ash, thanks for your reply. i get your point. that is exactly what i need.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still interested in interacting with `TFRecords` and `tf.data.Example`, there exists a library, created by NVIDIA, with MIT licence, called *go-tfdata*: https://github.com/NVIDIA/go-tfdata

It can transform any source of records/samples into set of `tf.data.Example` - `TFRecord` file.

Additionally, it natively supports TAR archives to TFRecord conversion.

From examples - converting TAR to TFRecord is as simple as:

```
pipeline := NewPipeline().FromTar(inFile).SampleToTFExample().ToTFRecord(outFile)
pipeline.Do()
```